# Why didn't God reveal all the answers to life?

Tags: reference-request

Is there scripture that supports why all these questions have not been revealed to us?
As a Christian, I do not ponder on unanswered questions, however I would have to believe, somewhere within the bible there has to be an answer to this simple question.

Comment: `As a Christian, I do not ponder on unanswered questions` -- Isn't this question a bit of an antithesis to that statement? :)

Comment: Depends on whether this (the question of why there are unanswered questions) is indeed an unanswered question :-P

Comment: @MattGutting: Well, it is, as of now, an unanswered question to the OP! :)

Comment: As far as I am concerned God did reveal all answers to life. You are going to have to specify what you think he did not answer.

Comment: Should be close as it is an opinion / truth seeking question and lack of research.  I cannot believe it was upvoted.

Comment: @TheFreemason Well, I would tend toward too broad. There are at least a hundred verses that can be used to support an answer to this. Just the difference between what we need to know and what we want to know is a massive topic that needs to be addressed before this could. But I'll go with primarily opinion based to follow suit of the previous close voters.

Answer (score 5):

> It is the glory of God to conceal a matter; to search out a matter is the glory of kings. (Proverbs 25:2, NIV)

There's a sense in which mysteries bring glory to God and solving them bring glory to us. It's no accident that so many people enjoy puzzles and riddles or exploration and experimentation, it's just another way in which we reflect the God whose image we are made in.

Comment: +1 Exactly the same scripture verse that I was thinking of. God wants to glorify us. So  he hides many things, including himself, so that we can search them/him out.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most applicable Scripture comes from Isaiah chapter 55:

> Isaiah 55:8 and 9 KJV For my thoughts are not your thoughts, neither are your ways my ways, saith the LORD. For as the heavens are higher than the earth, so are my ways higher than your ways, and my thoughts than your thoughts.

We seem to forget a few things about God that we really need to understand better. From the Southern Baptist perspective, we consider that God is omniscient, omnipotent, and omnipresent. Or in other words God knows all, sees all, and runs all.

To this end we do not have either the right or the ability to question anything God does, says and most especially what God's plans are.

So to your question;

That Scripture to us says it all.

1. God knew long before he even created the Universe everything that would happen throughout the life of our planet.
2. God saw even those things which we thought were hidden behind closed doors and in the middle of the night.
3. God was standing right next to you when you said your last swear word, or stole that cookie from the cookie jar after your mother told you not to take it.

And even knowing all of this ahead of time he went ahead and created things anyway, I along with many others; have I'm sure, wondered; since we are so far from how he wanted us to stay, when he created man to start with; why he didn't just forget the whole thing to start with?

The only answer to that has to be that God has some master plan that only he knows for his creation, and if he chose that we not understand that plan and its final outcome until he decides enough is enough, then as God he has every right to keep it from us.

We, and I include myself, often forget our place in relation to God. He is sovereign and not us, we answer to him he doesn't answer to us.

Therefore to answer your question:

"Is there scripture that deals with why God didn't reveal all the answers to life?"

the answer is yes:

and it is in many old testament Scriptures; it says:

> I am the LORD your God.